# Excel VBA Script throwing 'Object Required' on R1C1 Reference

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a very simple piece of code in VBA for Excel which will average 10 numbers and then iterate, averaging the next 10 numbers, for a certain number of iterations.

Problem is, I keep getting an 'Object Required' error on the line with the R1C1 calculation. I'm incredibly rusty with VBA at the moment and can't quite put my finger on what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be fantastic.

```
Sub Averaging()

Dim X As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim Z As Double

X = 5
Y = 5
Z = 0

For X = 5 To 65

Z = Y + 9

    Cells(5, X).Select
    ActiveCells.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-3], Z : RC[-3], Z])"

Y = Y + 10

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCell not ActiveCells......................